Brazilian kid killed by police officer for stealing a book
What I remember from this movie is that only scene.
It is a brazilian movie, there is this scene that takes place in a train station where a kid steals a book from a woman. A police officer runs ater him on the train tracks and then kills him.
That was very shocking to me.
I saw this movie on TV around 2005 I think.
I think the main character is the woman who has been stolen.

There's a very similar scene in the Brazilian Oscar nominee Central Station from 1998. A kid thief is chased by cops in a train station, is caught and then shot to death. But I don't think he steals a book, I think it's a radio or something. See if the trailer rings any bells.

@Walt Yes now that I see that it is about a woman who writes letters for people, I think this is the one. Thank you, I'll check if I can find it.

@Walt Yes that's exactly the movie I was looking for Walt ! Thank you very much, if you add an answer, I'll accept it nP.

No problem, coming right up. Glad you found it.

You're looking for the Brazilian drama Central Station from 1998.

Dora, a dour old woman, works at a Rio de Janeiro central station, writing letters for customers and mailing them. She hates customers and calls them 'trash'. Josue is a 9-year-old boy who never met his father. His mother is sending letters to his father through Dora. When she dies in a car accident, Dora takes Josue and takes a trip with him to find his father. 

At one point, a kid steals something from a booth in the train station. He's chased by local cops, caught and cruelly shot to death. The film was nominated for a Best Foreign Language Film Oscar and star Fernanda Montenegro was nominated for Best Actress. Here's the trailer:



